# Flutter: How do ListViews and other Scrollables determine their size?

Tags: listview, dart, nested, flutter

I took some time to understand the layout behavior of `Container`, which I do now. But I just can't figure how `ListViews` determine their size. I know that `shrinkWrapping` works in the `main axis`, but what about the `cross axis`? I searched the documentation for this and I found nothing.

Why does this

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyHomePage()
        )
      );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, item) {
              return Text("Why does this not work?!");
            },
          );
        },
      );
    }
}
```

report `'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.` ?
There is a very detailed explanation about how `Container` gets layed out. I am trying to reach the same understanding for these `Widgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cross axis of ListView/GridView always fill its parent.